# Kohana 3.3 controllers in subfolders

Tags: php, routes, kohana

I have controllers

```
--controllers
  --Administrator
    -Base.php
    -Admin.php (extend Base.php)
-controller1.php
-controller2.php
-etc
```

And my route looks like this

```
    Route::set('administrator', 'Administrator(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'Administrator',
    'controller' => 'base',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Try to load this controller and i get message Not found

What's wrong?

### UPDATE!

```
class Controller_Administrator_Base extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = 'panel/index';

    public function action_index(){
        echo 'kupakonia';
    }
} // End Welcome
```

All routes. I was trying alot of sugesstions from google and nothing helps, and I write something becouse i cant update this tobic becouse is too much code inside.

Still can't update.

> ```
> Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
> ->defaults(array(
>     'controller' => 'read',
>     'action'     => 'index',
> ));
> ```

```
Route::set('user', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'user',
    'action'     => 'index',
));

Route::set('administrator', 'administrator(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'Administrator',
    'controller' => 'base',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Any sugestions?

Ps. still can't update this topic :/ Wtf must be more characters in tekst than in code ? 
this is my first asc on stackoverflow. So sorry for this ;)

Comment: The route looks fine, could you give us the class name of your Controller?

Comment: I was trying a lot of sets and isn't work ;p

Comment: Do you have more routes in your bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, I do, 2 more routes. Topic updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two catch all routes (`default` and `user`) in your Bootstrap file. These two routes do exactly the same.

Also, since these routes are catch all and the order of the routes matter, this means if the catch all route is the first it will match all URLs.

Try this:

```
Route::set('administrator', 'administrator(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'Administrator',
    'controller' => 'base',
    'action'     => 'index',
));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
 ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'read',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Another thing, it is usually bad practice to have a catch all route. Try to create routes specific for your `Controllers`.

Comment: Thanks! I start my work with kohana and i was thinking to one controller i need one route :p thanks that's working!